Vitest Stuck when running in a Docker Container
I would like to run the Vitest Unit tests of my Nuxt application on Github Actions in a Docker container, but the tests do not start, but get stuck on the output to be seen below. I'm currently running the container only locally, because I don't want to push every time I try a new change. Locally outside of the container the tests are running just fine.
2024-11-25 06:25:56 
2024-11-25 06:25:56  DEV  v2.1.5 /app
2024-11-25 06:25:56

Dockerfile:
FROM  oven/bun:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN bun install

CMD ["bun", "vitest"]

Nuxt Config:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    // NUXT CONFIGURATION
    compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
    devtools: {
        enabled: true,

        timeline: {
            enabled: true,
        },
    },

    build: {
        transpile: ['@vuepic/vue-datepicker'],
    },

    components: [{ path: '~/components/global', pathPrefix: false }, '~/components'],

    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            apiAddress: process.env.API_ADDRESS,
            isSelfHosted: process.env.SELF_HOSTED === 'true',
        },
    },

    app: {
        head: {
            link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.png' }],
        },
    },

    css: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css'],

    // MODULES & MODULE CONFIGURATION
    modules: [
        '@nuxt/image',
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
        '@nuxt/test-utils/module',
        '@pinia/nuxt',
        'nuxt-aos',
        'floating-vue/nuxt',
        // '@sidebase/nuxt-auth',
    ],

    tailwindcss: {
        cssPath: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css', { injectPosition: 'last' }],
    },

    image: {
        dir: 'assets/media',
    },

    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            autoprefixer: {},
            tailwindcss: {},
            'postcss-nested': {},
        },
    },
});


Vitest Config (MTS):
import { defineVitestConfig } from '@nuxt/test-utils/config';

export default defineVitestConfig({
    test: {
        environment: 'nuxt',
    },
});


